# Typesetting graphs of Turing machines

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, xparse

I have to typeset a lot of graphs of automatons looking like this.

[image: Example of a graph of a Turing machine]

Therefore, I spent a lot of effort on introducing a simplied syntax based on TikZ. I got much help from here working out one or the other detail. Now I can share the overall implementation.

```
 \documentclass[fontsize=11pt, paper=a4, DIV=9]{scrartcl}

 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

 \usepackage{lmodern}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{relsize}
 \usepackage{xparse}
 \usepackage{tikz}

 \makeatletter

 % character used in a formal language
 % \Char{}  expands to the empty word
 % \Char{~} expands to the blank character of a Turing machine
 % \Char{#} expands to the bottom-of-stack character of a pushdown automaton
 \ExplSyntaxOn
 \NewDocumentCommand{\Char}{>{\TrimSpaces}m}
 {
   \str_case_x:nnF{\tl_to_str:n{#1}}
   {
     {    }           {\mbox{$\varepsilon$}}
     { ## }           {\mbox{\texttt{\#}}}
     { \c_tilde_str } {\mbox{\textscale{.87}{$\Box$}}}
   }
   {\mbox{\texttt{#1}}}
 }
 \ExplSyntaxOff

 % state of an automaton
 \newcommand{\State}[1]{#1}

 % graph of a Turing machine
 \newenvironment{GraphTM}[1][]{\begin{scope}[#1]}{\end{scope}}

 % state in a graph of a Turing machine
 % #1 = identifier 
 % #2 = state label
 % #3 = "initial" and/or "accepting" (separated by comma)
 % #4 = position in the format "(<x>, <y>)"
 \NewDocumentCommand{\StateTM}{ r() m O{} r() }{%
   \node [state, #3] at (#4) (#1) {$\State{#2}$};}

 % transition in a graph of a Turing machine
 % #1 = identifier of the current state
 % #2 = edge modifier using TikZ syntax
 % #3 = identifier of the subsequent state
 % #4 = position of the edge label using TikZ syntax
 % #5 = edge label
 \NewDocumentCommand{\TransTM}{ r() O{} r() O{} m  }{%
   \path [trans] (#1) edge [#2] node [#4] {\IT@TM@Edge@Label{#5}} (#3);}

 % internal commands used by \TransTM
 \newcommand{\IT@TM@Trans}[3]{%
   \makebox[.6em]{\Char{#1}};\;\makebox[.6em]{\Char{#2}},\,\Char{#3}}
 \NewDocumentCommand{\IT@TM@Edge@Item}{>{\SplitArgument{2}{,}}m}{%
   \IT@TM@Edge@Delim\IT@TM@Trans#1}
 \NewDocumentCommand{\IT@TM@Edge@Label}{>{\SplitList{|}}m}{%
   \def\IT@TM@Edge@Delim{\gdef\IT@TM@Edge@Delim{\\}}
   \shortstack{\ProcessList{#1}{\IT@TM@Edge@Item}}}

 \makeatother

 \usetikzlibrary{automata}

 \tikzset{>=stealth, semithick}
 \tikzset{initial text=}
 \tikzset{state/.style={font=\small, minimum size=0pt, circle, draw}}
 \tikzset{trans/.style={font=\footnotesize, ->}}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{GraphTM}
 % States
 \StateTM (z0) {z_0} [initial]   ( 0, 0)
 \StateTM (z1) {z_1}             ( 3, 0)
 \StateTM (z2) {z_2}             ( 6, 0)
 \StateTM (z3) {z_3}             ( 9, 0)
 \StateTM (z4) {z_4}             (-2, 3)
 \StateTM (z5) {z_5} [accepting] ( 2, 3)
 % Transitions
 \TransTM (z0)                (z1) [above]    {a, x, R}         
 \TransTM (z0)                (z4) [left=3pt] {y, y, R}          
 \TransTM (z0)                (z5) [left=3pt] {~, ~, N}
 \TransTM (z1) [loop above]   (z1) [above]    {a, a, R | y, y, R}
 \TransTM (z1)                (z2) [above]    {b, y, R}
 \TransTM (z2) [loop above]   (z2) [above]    {b, b, R | z, z, R}
 \TransTM (z2)                (z3) [above]    {c, z, L}
 \TransTM (z3) [loop above]   (z3) [above]    {a, a, L | b, b, L | y, y, L | z, z, L}
 \TransTM (z3) [bend left=23] (z0) [below]    {x, x, R}
 \TransTM (z4) [loop above]   (z4) [above]    {y, y, R | z, z, R}
 \TransTM (z4)                (z5) [above]    {~, ~, N}
 \end{GraphTM}
 \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

Everything between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` is part of a package I am writing.

There are some commands and environments such as `\State{}` and `GraphTM` that do nothing at all at the moment. They are intended for later modifications of the layout.

I do not make use of relative positioning such as `[right = ... of ...]` yet. This feature can be implemented later as needed.

What do you think about the implementation? Am I doing something odd that could cause problems I am not aware of?

Comment: Well, you are not following best practice for the use of expl3 stuff: inconsistent syntax with `xparse` macros used to do more than provide a user interface. `\Char` should be a wrapper around a function defined with `\cs_new...` or so. Use of `\mbox` etc. here is odd. (The `\texttt` can't be helped unless you define an expl3 equivalent, but box and space macros are certainly available.) Consider using a key-value interface rather than defining document-level macros taking multiple arguments with hard-to-remember syntax.

Comment: Why do you need to implement relative positioning? Design your code so that it uses the existing implementation. This shouldn't be something you need to add as needed. It should just work given that it is there already. Just make sure that your code doesn't break it - don't break it and then try to re-implement it.

Comment: @cfr In the original TikZ syntax, it seems inconsistent to me that absolute positioning using `at (<x>, <y>)` and relative positioning using, e.g., `[right = ... of ...]` have to occur at different places of `\node`.

Comment: Maybe. But, even if that is true, designing an interface which bucks that inconsistency will introduce an even more confusing inconsistency. If you just plan to use the code yourself, that's obviously a matter of your preferences. But if you plan to inflict it on others, they will not thank you for re-thinking design decisions already made in Ti*k*Z, even if those decisions are sub-optimal. To put this another way: it will be even further below optimality to choose syntax which might have been more optimal if chosen for Ti*k*Z in place of some sub-optimal syntax actually chosen.

Comment: Note that the distinction is a false one anyway. `+(<x>,<y>)` and `++(<x>,<y>)` are certainly relative, as are `([xshift=<x>,yshift=<y>]<name>)`and `([shift=<angle>:<dimension>]<name>)`.

Comment: Also, I would recommend having the optional before the required argument for `\StateTM`, for example. In general, it is most unwise to buck this trend and sometimes spells trouble down the road (in addition to introducing inconsistent syntax likely to confuse). Again, if this is just for you, it's your preference. So much of this only applies if you plan to share the code you're writing.

Comment: Shouldn't the `GraphTM` environment open and close a `tikzpicture` environment (instead of a `scope environment`)?

Comment: Need to change `\str_case_x:nnF` to `\str_case_e:nnF` as of this year :)